# Jenkins Github Pull Request Builder Plugin throwing user authentication error

Tags: jenkins, github, devops

I'm using https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin plugin for my Jenkins to initiate job build when pull request is raised.
I'm getting below error
"Unable to connect to GitHub API: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"}"

Tried with multiple user on 2 different Jenkins, issue remains same.

[image]

Comment: Are you using github password or access token for authentication?

Comment: Github username and password

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are using github username and password. But you need to use github access token instead of password for authentication. You can create an access token from `settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access tokens -> Generate new token`.

Comment: Glad to help bro :)